# iOS XML Parsed Data Comparison

Tags: iphone, xml, ios, nsxmlparser

I am parsing data using the NSXMLParser delegate. I know the data is being parsed because I can call upon it in the NSLog. I am having trouble running a conditional statement that compares whether a string equals a certain value.

Here is my code:

```
NSString *status = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [attributeDict objectForKey:@"status"]];

NSLog(@"Status: %@", status);

if (status == @"1") {
    NSLog(@"Test succeeded!");
}
```

The NSString 'status' will read '1' in the NSLog, but the if statement above will not be called. Is this a casting problem?

Thank you in advance.

Cheers, Evan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `isEqualToString` function of `NSString`.

So your code would be like below.

```
if ([status isEqualToString:@"1"]) 
{
    NSLog(@"Test succeeded!");
}
```

Read [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) documentation

Comment: yes, yes.. stackoverflow is asking me to wait a few minutes before accepting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *status = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [attributeDict objectForKey:@"status"]];

NSLog(@"Status: %@", status);

if ([status isEqualToString:@"1"] == TRUE) {
    NSLog(@"Test succeeded!");
}
```

More information about [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)